# Changing names of the files found with File::Find

Tags: perl

Hi consider this Perl code:

```
for my $line  (@files){
    #print "$line\n";
    if ($line =~ /gene\/(\w.+)\s\w+\/(\w.+)(\.\S.+\.\S.+\.gz)/){
        #print "$line\n";
        @array = split ('\t', $1);
        my $path = $array[0];
        foreach my $pathi (sort(keys(%legend))){
            foreach my $name ( keys %{$legend{$pathi}}){
                foreach my $sample ( keys %{$legend{$pathi}{$name}}){
                    if ($pathi =~ $path){
                        my $dirsearch = "/Users/bob/Desktop/gene_ex/";
                        find(\&wantede, $dirsearch);
                        sub wantede {
                                if ($_ eq $name){
                                    my $finalname = "$sample\_$name";
                                    rename ($File::Find::name, "$File::Find::dir/$finalname") or print "Rename error";
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What i want to do is search for a particular file and attach another branch at the name: the find function goes exactly like this when but when i try to find the $name inside i got an error that $name is not declared or something. I've controlled all the hashes and they are fine, i can't figure out what is wrong. If i make the concatenation first, i get every time the same name on the files

In @files there are all the files within the working directory
In %legend is a hash where the first key is the name of the folder, second key is filename, third key is a string.

Comment: Why are you running find in the inner loop? Surely you'd want it in the outer loop, and just do all the logic within your `wanted` function?

Comment: What is in `@files`? What is in `%legend`? It doesn't make much sense to declare your `wanted()` subroutine so deep within your loops.

Comment: Edited with explanation. I've tried the same exact code with the wanted outide but i get same problems

Comment: "Edited with explanation" - well barely :-/ I'm sorry if it seems like we're being difficult. We're really not. You obviously understand exactly what is going here as you have been investigating this problem for some time. But if you re-read your question from the perspective of someone with no prior knowledge of the situation, I think you'll see that we really don't have enough information to be much help. We'd like to help you, but you need to help us to help you by answering our questions with as much detail as you can.

Comment: You should write stepwise comment in your code and give sample value of what is that you have and what do you want?

Comment: "I've tried the same exact code with the wanted outide but i get same problems" Oh, I'm sure that's true. I wasn't suggesting that would fix any of your problems. I meant that it was a strange place to define a subroutine and it will almost certainly confuse someone who maintains the code after you.

Comment: 1st, Listen to Sobrique.  Putting `find` *inside* the loops seems inside-out at best and wildly inefficient at worst.  2nd, If you insist on putting the `find` inside, consider an anonymous subroutine defined *inside* find's parameter list instead of a named subroutine that reeks of closure inside the loops but only gets compiled once.

Comment: Of course you could always run your code in the debugger, put a breakpoint on the subroutine and verify that `$name` & `$finalname` change each iteration instead of being closed over.